# CSS responsiveness, inline-divs with unequal heights

Tags: css

If we style multiple divs with property display set to "inline-block" and one of them has a height longer than the others, all the smaller divs align at the bottom creating extra space at the top. But all I wanted is that the smaller divs align at the top and leave any extra space at the bottom. Is there any way I can achieve the required effect?[image: image describing the problem]

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align: top` for inline-block `div`s does that. [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

```css
.b{
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}

.ib {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align: top; /*this line*/
}

.d1 {
  height: 100px;
}

.d2, .d3 {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="ib d1"></div>
  <div class="ib d2"></div>
  <div class="ib d3"></div>
</div>
```